# Pop OS, How to enable boot messages to be printed on screen during boot up

Tags: boot, systemd-boot

In Ubuntu I know how can I enable post message from below link But currently I'm using [Pop! OS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pop!_OS) is same branch/implementation from Ubuntu but I can not find way how can I enable post message at boot time, as above mention steps there don't have any files (maybe because it not GRUB system)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! Your question is lacking clarity. Do you want to see the messages printed by the kernel/systemd during boot? Do you want to see them only once for troubleshooting or do you want to enable them permanently? Please edit your question to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

First open terminal in pop-os.
& type below command

```
sudo su
```

& gain root access

```
cd /boot/efi/loader/entries/
```

& enter in boot loader entries

Then you can see below files,

```
root@symdroid:/boot/efi/loader/entries# ll
drwx------ 2 root root 4096 May 13 22:56 ./
drwx------ 3 root root 4096 May 25 15:38 ../
-rwx------ 1 root root  256 May 23 01:34 Pop_OS-current.conf*
-rwx------ 1 root root  256 Apr 24 21:55 Pop_OS-current.conf_bkup*
-rwx------ 1 root root  274 May 23 01:34 Pop_OS-oldkern.conf*
```

here you can find this file **Pop_OS-current.conf**
you have to change this file configuration for to enable post message 
for safe side backup this file 
as

```
cp -rf  Pop_OS-current.conf  Pop_OS-current.conf_backup_for_postmsg
```

Than open file

```
cat Pop_OS-current.conf

title Pop!_OS
linux /EFI/Pop_OS-224475f6-6dcf-48eb-b530-5edd806eddfe/vmlinuz.efi
initrd /EFI/Pop_OS-224475f6-6dcf-48eb-b530-5edd806eddfe/initrd.img
options root=UUID=224475f6-6dcf-48eb-b530-5edd806eddfe ro quiet loglevel=0 systemd.show_status=false splash
```

you have to change file as follows,
as 
remove keyword as **quiet**, **splash**
& edit **systemd.show_status=false** this to **systemd.show_status=true**

& now

```
title Pop!_OS
linux /EFI/Pop_OS-224475f6-6dcf-48eb-b530-5edd806eddfe/vmlinuz.efi
initrd /EFI/Pop_OS-224475f6-6dcf-48eb-b530-5edd806eddfe/initrd.img
options root=UUID=224475f6-6dcf-48eb-b530-5edd806eddfe ro loglevel=0 systemd.show_status=true
```

save this file with above changes & on next boot time you able to see post message

*******Here only drawback is on each time boot configuration update we need to do above changes.**

Answer (score 2):

Not going to take credit by reposting:

https://saputra.org/threads/disable-boot-splash-screen-on-pop-_os-20-04-desktop-linux.197/

Use "new" command kernelstub

Comment: You don't have to take credit, but you should [edit] and include the details from the link in your answer. When the link dies your answer won't be very useful.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/404899)

Answer (score 1):

According to the [systemd-boot documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/systemd-boot/) you have to edit `/boot/loader/loader.conf` and remove the `quiet` parameter from the `options` entry.

Answer (score 0):

Don't have permanent  solution but clicking arrow up key at time of boot worked for me
I hope it may work for you